# How to sum a calculated a field on top of another calculated field?

Tags: tableau-api

The current issue I have maybe a bit difficult to describe but I will do my best.

Currently, in my workbook, I am experiencing duplicates at the product level so I created a calculated field to work around that. I wanted to know which individual products have not been quoted the past year so the answer should be **1** for not quoted and **0** for quoted, I worked around that by doing an if statement with % products not quoted the formula looks as such:

```
IF [% Not Quoted] > 0 
then 1 
else 0 
end
```

which I named **Prod Not Quoted.** That worked great for me,

however now I want do the count or sum(?) of products not quoted at the vendor level which would mean my products not quoted needs to be grouped by the vendor name. To be specific my objective is to provide a table of all products not quoted by vendor name without duplicates at the product level. What I tried to do is create a new calculated field using the previously which I calculated as the following:

```
IF [Prod Not Quoted] = 1 
then sum(1) 
else 0 
end
```

The latter calculation, however, gave me the sum of all products quoted and not quoted along with the duplicates I am trying to avoid. Why would  **IF [prod Not Quoted] = 1 then sum(1) else 0 end** not work?

Someone on tableau forum with the following suggestion

```
SUM (IF [Prod Not Quoted] = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

however I got the error cannot sum something that is not already aggregated.

Is there any kind of work around to the issue I am having?

Comment: can you show tableau design how and where you are calculating the second of the calcualted field

Answer (score 0):

If you have duplicates at the dimension level you can use the FIXED calculation to select just a single row at the dimension level. For example:

```
{FIXED [Product]: MAX(quoted)}
```

What this is doing is saying "for each Product, what is the max quoted value?" So if you have duplicates, it'll return only one value

Now we are solving the duplicates problem we can wrap it in SUM:

```
SUM({FIXED [Product]: MAX(quoted)})
```

To answer your question about why the sum isn't working, it's because you're trying to do a sum of a sum. If you still wanted to take the approach that was offered to you then you could change it to:

```
IF [Prod Not Quoted] = 1 
then {FIXED [Product]: MAX(quoted)}  
end
```

(I called the aggregation field quoted, but it'll be the measure you're working with)